# textmate regex date search

Tags: regex, date, textmate

I'm using text mate to search for date strings in the format `30/08/2016` and tried adding this to the regex find panel: `^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$`
but it yields no results

Comment: Try `\b\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\b`

Answer (score 1):

You are using beginning of the string `^` and end of the string `$`. Therefore, it only works, if you have a sample string like this: `12/12/1212` but not like this: `abc12/12/1212def`. You also have to escape a forward slash `/`.

If you don't care about this string being inside the text, you can use

```
\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}
```

If you know, that there is white space around it, you can use this:

```
(?<=\s)(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})(?=\s)
```

Or the simpler solution with word boundaries `\b`

```
\b\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\b
```

*Don't forget to use the global flag, if you are trying to match multiple instance of this date pattern.*